# Quick, secure Text Snippet/File sharing app?

Tags: windows

Where I work, we often have to share small pieces of text and/or files quickly and temporarily.

I'd like to know if there is an app that works over the local network to quickly share pieces of text and small files with another person connected to our local network?

An ideal example would be a taskbar app that you can right click, and select "Share Text Snippet" and a box will pop-up, prompting me to enter some text, and then select a user to sent it to. These text snippets/files should not be stored anywhere permanently.

Currently we just send an email, but for obvious reasons that is awkward.

Comment: Ok, this sets the stage for owncloud in conjunction with a password manager like KeePass. Store the password there, and let owncloud do the sync. What about that?

Comment: It is in the pipeline to introduce an office-wide password manager, so we can just share a password with a specific person in the office. But it's not just passwords, it's often snippets of code, or just a bit of text. Setting up a self-hosted cloud hosting for this is probably a bit overkill for the odd sending of files.

I think I've found myself a concept to work on here in my own time. Was thinking of using electron framework to build an app for this, that works over the LAN, and detects other devices on the network that have the app active on their device. Expect to see this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP Messenger (http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en) is a messenger for local network only. I would use it in school to talk with friends where access to other services would be blocked. Its a single exe and can be easily brought to other computers and supports sending of files, statuses like online, away or custom made.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I described. Although this *looks* like it hasn't been touched since 1995 (I know it has, though), it's actually really good. I can just drag and drop a file, send text, and it has good encryption features. 

Thanks for the good find!

Answer (score 0):

What about any kind of messenger apps, like Skype, Threema et al.?

They can
- share text
- share files

However, of course, they are stored somewhere, but if it's not a privacy concern, you do not need to care about that.

Both [Skype](https://www.skype.com/de/business/) and [Threema](https://work.threema.ch/en) also have business versions, which may better address this specific need too.

Comment: Often, we have to send a database file, or a secure password to another colleague quickly.  Sometimes, these databases are from our high-profile international clients, so having them stored in the cloud is a no-no. Writing down a 16 digital random password is a pain, so temporary, local storage and automatic deletion after a set period of time would be ideal.

Thank you, though.